# How to extract internal words using regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to match only the street name from a series of addresses.  The addresses might look like:

> 23 Barrel Rd.
>
> 14 Old Mill Dr.
>
> 65-345 Howard's Bluff

I want to use a regex to match "Barrel", "Old Mill", and "Howard's".  I need to figure out how to exclude the last word.  So far I have a lookbehind to exclude the digits, and I can include the words and spaces and "'" by using this:

```
(?<=\d\s)(\w|\s|\')+
```

How can I exclude the final word (which may or may not end in a period)?  I figure I should be using a lookahead, but I can't figure out how to formulate it.

Comment: Your original regex doesn't account for the fact that there's a dash in the first group of numbers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a look-behind for this:

```
/^[-\d]+ ([\w ']+) \w+\.?$/
```

- Match one or more digits and hyphens
- space
- match letters, digits, spaces, apostrophes into capture group 1
- space
- match a final word and an optional period

An example Ruby implementation:

```
regex = /^[-\d]+ ([\w ']+) \w+\.?$/

tests = [ "23 Barrel Rd.",  "14 Old Mill Dr.", "65-345 Howard's Bluff" ]

tests.each do |test|
  p test.match(regex)[1]
end
```

Output:

```
"Barrel"
"Old Mill"
"Howard's"
```

Comment: That does the trick.  I'm still getting used to the syntax, and I think I just learned something about the utility of capture groups.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the lookahead you want is `(?=\s\w+\.?$)`.

`\s`: you don't want to include the last space
`\w`: at least one word-character (A-Z, a-z, 0-9, or '_')
`\.?`: optional period (for abbreviations such as "St.")
`$`: make sure this is the last word

If there's a possibility that there might be additional whitespace before the newline, just change this to `(?=\s\w+\.?\s*$)`.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just match what you want? If I have understood well you need to get all the words after the numbers excluding the last word. Words are separated by space so just get everything between numbers and the last space.

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/dD3rW9)

`\d+(?:-\d+)? ((?:.)+)`  Note: there's a space at the end.

Tha will end up with what you want in \1 N times.

If you just want to match the exact text you may use `\K` (not supported by every regex engine) but: [Example](http://regex101.com/r/wB8oO8)

With the regex `\d+(?:-\d+)? \K.+(?= )`

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use the `split()` function provided in most scripting languages. Here's the Python version of what you want:

`stname = address.split()[1:-1]`

(Here `address` is the original address line, and `stname` is the name of the street, i.e., what you're trying to extract.)